# Model binding in the controller when form is posted - navigation properties are not loaded automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, model-binding

I'm using the Entity Framework version 4.2. There are two classes in my small test app:

```
public class TestParent
{
    public int TestParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TestChild> TestChildren { get; set; }
}

public class TestChild
{
    public int TestChildID { get; set; }
    public int TestParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual TestParent TestParent { get; set; }
}
```

Populating objects with data from the database works well. So I can use `testParent.TestChildren.OrderBy(tc => tc.Name).First().Name` etc. in my code.

Then I built a standard edit form for my testParents. The controller look like this:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private EFDbTestParentRepository testParentRepository = new EFDbTestParentRepository();
    private EFDbTestChildRepository testChildRepository = new EFDbTestChildRepository();

    public ActionResult ListParents()
    {
        return View(testParentRepository.TestParents);
    }

    public ViewResult EditParent(int testParentID)
    {
        return View(testParentRepository.TestParents.First(tp => tp.TestParentID == testParentID));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditParent(TestParent testParent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            testParentRepository.SaveTestParent(testParent);
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("Changes to test parents have been saved: {0} (ID = {1})",
                                                        testParent.Name,
                                                        testParent.TestParentID);
            return RedirectToAction("ListParents");
        }
        // something wrong with the data values
        return View(testParent);
    }
}
```

When the form is posted back to the server the model binding appears to be working well - i.e. testParent looks okay (id, name and comment set as expected). However the navigation property TestChildren remains at NULL.

This I guess is not sooo surprising since the model binding merely extracts the form values as they were sent from the browser and pushes them into an object of the TestParent class. Populating testParent.TestChildren however requires an immediate roundtrip to the database which is the responsibility of the Entity Framework. And EF probably doesn't get involved in the binding process.

I was however expecting the lazy loading to kick in when I call `testParent.TestChildren.First()`. Instead that leads to an ArgumentNullException.

Is it necessary to tag an object in a special way after model binding so that the Entity Framework will do lazy loading? How can I achieve this?

Obviously I could manually retrieve the children with the second repository `testChildRepository`. But that (a) doesn't feel right and (b) leads to problems with the way my repositories are set up (each using their own DBContext - which is an issue that I haven't managed to come to terms with yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get lazy loading for your child collection two requirements must be fulfilled:

- The parent entity must be attached to an EF context
- Your parent entity must be a lazy loading proxy

Both requirements are met if you load the parent entity from the database through a context (and your navigation properties are `virtual` to allow proxy creation).

If you don't load the entity from the database but create it manually you can achieve the same by using the appropriate EF functions:

```cs
var parent = context.TestParents.Create();
parent.TestParentID = 1;
context.TestParents.Attach(parent);
```

Using `Create` and not `new` is important here because it creates the required lazy loading proxy. You can then access the child collection and the children of parent with ID = 1 will be loaded lazily:

```cs
var children = parent.TestChildren; // no NullReferenceException
```

Now, the default modelbinder has no clue about those specific EF functions and will simply instantiate the parent with `new` and also doesn't attach it to any context. Both requirements are not fulfilled and lazy loading cannot work.

You could write your own model binder to create the instance with `Create()` but this is probably the worst solution as it would make your view layer very EF dependent.

If you need the child collection after model binding I would in this case load it via explicit loading:

```cs
// parent comes as parameter from POST action method
context.TestParents.Attach(parent);
context.Entry(parent).Collection(p => p.TestChildren).Load();
```

If your context and EF is hidden behind a repository you will need a new repository method for this, like:

```cs
void LoadNavigationCollection<TElement>(T entity,
    Expression<Func<T, ICollection<TElement>>> navigationProperty) 
    where TElement : class
{
    _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    _context.Entry(entity).Collection(navigationProperty).Load();
}
```

...where `_context` is a member of the repository class.

But the better way, as Darin mentioned, is to bind ViewModels and then map them to your entities as needed. Then you would have the option to instantiate the entities with `Create()`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and sorry for my late response. I have been offline for the last three days and pretty swamped. I guess your explanation showed me that there are some fundamental holes in my knowledge of EF. I have worked through the Contoso University example on the Microsoft website and some introductory articles. Could you maybe recommend a resource that I can use to move a bit further?

Comment: Regarding your last remark about binding to ViewModels: that's a technique that I wasn't aware of. I am using ViewModels but only to pass them into views. Could you maybe explain why it's of advantage to use a view model instead of a class from my domain model? Since I'm pretty much displaying all properties of my class as input fields in the initial view wouldn´t the view model look just like my class? Which means that I need to keep the two in sync as I add more properties. If I use Html.EditorForModel() in the view of the GET request then it won't need to be adjusted properties are added.

Comment: @ralfonso: Julia Lerman has written a book about Code-First: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Entity-Framework-Code-First/dp/1449312942 and written articles and created videos: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/code-first-entity-framework-4-1-videos-and-articles-on-msdn/ I you like learning by watching videos I'd recommend Pluralsight: http://www.pluralsight-training.net (they have stuff about MVC and EF and a lot of other subjects). A few of there videos are free, but the commercial subscriptions are quite affordable too.

Comment: @ralfonso: I'd recommend to make a new question from your second comment. That's a too big subject to explain in a comment here. One thing is correct: "Working with ViewModels = Writing more code and more to maintain". But this additional code has a lot of benefits.

Comment: Awesome - thank you very much for the links. I'll open up a second question regarding the advantages of using view models for form posts.

Comment: As you suggested - here is the new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994804/model-binding-in-controller-when-form-is-posted-why-to-use-view-model-instead) on the benefis of using view models in model binding.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use hidden fields inside the form that will store the values of the child collection:

```
@model TestParent
@using (Html.BegniForm())
{
    ... some input fields of the parent

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TestChildren)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and then have an editor template for the children containing the hidden fields (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TestChild.cshtml`):

```
@model TestChild
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TestChildID)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
...
```

But since you are not following good practices here and are directly passing your domain models to the view instead of using view models you will have a problem with the recursive relationship you have between the children and parents. You might need to manually populate the parent for each children.

But a better way would be to query your database in the POST action and fetch the children that are associated to the given parent since the user cannot edit the children inside the view anyway.

Comment: I agree that I could manually query the database for the child records. But isn't it one of the features of the Entity Framework that I don't have to worry about that any more?  Whenever I have an object I can traverse down into it without worrying about how (and when) the object is populated from the database - at least that was my (admittedly hopeful) understanding.