# Model binding in controller when form is posted - why to use view model instead of class from domain model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, model-binding

I'm still reasonably new to ASP.NET MVC 3. I have come across view models and their use for passing data from a controller to the view. In my recent [question on model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883264/model-binding-in-the-controller-when-form-is-posted-navigation-properties-are) two experts suggested that I should use view models for model binding as well.

This is something I haven't come across before. But both guys have assured me that it is best practise. Could someone maybe shed some light on the reasons why view models are more suitable for model binding?

Here is an example situation: I have a simple class in my domain model.

```
public class TestParent
{
    public int TestParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private EFDbTestParentRepository testParentRepository = new EFDbTestParentRepository();
    private EFDbTestChildRepository testChildRepository = new EFDbTestChildRepository();

    public ActionResult ListParents()
    {
        return View(testParentRepository.TestParents);
    }

    public ViewResult EditParent(int testParentID)
    {
        return View(testParentRepository.TestParents.First(tp => tp.TestParentID == testParentID));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditParent(TestParent testParent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            testParentRepository.SaveTestParent(testParent);
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("Changes to test parents have been saved: {0} (ID = {1})",
                                                        testParent.Name,
                                                        testParent.TestParentID);
            return RedirectToAction("ListParents");
        }
        // something wrong with the data values
        return View(testParent);
    }
}
```

So in the third action method which gets invoked when an HTTP POST arrives I used TestParent for model binding. This felt quite convenient because the browser page that generates the HTTP POST request contains input fields for all properties of TestParent. And I actually thought that's the way the templates that Visual Studio provides for CRUD operations work as well.

However the recommendation that I got was that the signature of the third action method should read `public ActionResult EditParent(TestParentViewModel viewModel)`.

Comment: IMO, using a viewmodel or a model is dependent on the situation.   If the page uses only the attributes of a specific model then I think it is ok to strongly type the view to that model and go on.   If however there is some element that is not natively part of the model then that is where a viewmodel comes in to play.   Creating a viewmodel just to represent a model to the view kind of defeates the concept of DRY code.    This is one of those concepts where if you ask 10 developers you will get 12 answers.   Bottom line is using a model doesn't (as far as I know) violate the concept of MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds appealing at first, but as your models and view actions get increasingly complex, you start to see the value of using ViewModels for (most) everything, especially input scenarios.

- Case 1 - Most web frameworks are susceptible to over-posting.  If you are binding straight to your domain model, it is very possible to over-post data and maliciously change something not belonging to the user.  I find it cleaner to bind to an input view model than have long string lists of white lists or black lists, although there are some other interesting ways with binding to an interface.
- Case 2 - As your input grows in complexity, you'll run into times when you need to submit and validate fields not directly in the domain model ('I Agree' checkboxes, etc)
- Case 3 - More of a personal thing, but I find model binding to relational domain objects to be a giant pain at times.  Easier to link them up in AutoMapper than deal with MVC's modelbinder for complicated object graphs.  MVC's html helpers also work more smoothly against primitive types than deep relational models.

The negatives of using ViewModels is that it isn't very DRY.

So the moral of the story is, binding to domain models can be a viable solution for simple things, but as the complexity increases, it becomes easier to have a separate view model and then map between the two.

Comment: ViewModels fit into DRY just fine, as DRY generally applies to actual logic. Viewmodels, being generally properties and thats it - don't violate DRY even though it may seem it. If one is really concerned about property repetition, use a shared base for shared properties but there should be a good reason for that.